# CANNOT FIND SYMBOL

Tags: java, class, variables, symbols

I get a compile error with the simple output statement:

```
 System.out.println(j);
```

But without it, it compiles fine.

Secondly, each time the `for(condition)` is true, it will iterate, but how would it ever be 4/2 (wouldn't J iterate to 3)?

Hope that makes sense.

```
  public class FindFac {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

    for(int i = 2; i <= 50; i++) {
        System.out.print("Factors of " + i + ": ");
        for(int j = 2; j < i; j++)
            ***System.out.println(j);***
        if((i%j) == 0) System.out.print(j + " ");
        System.out.println();
    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a very silly mistake, you missed the opening and closing braces for the for loop :

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

        for (int i = 2; i <= 50; i++) {
            System.out.print("Factors of " + i + ": ");
            for (int j = 2; j < i; j++) {
                System.out.println(j);
                if ((i % j) == 0) System.out.print(j + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```